# Can SQL Server Reporting Services print multiple tables and charts on one page?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I'm new to SSRS and I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible with SSRS.  I have a list of 100+ schools in my data set.  I'd like to print one page per school, and for it to look like the picture below.  Each table and chart are using a unique data set, but it's all coming from one main table.

Can SSRS print two separate tables and 2 charts on the same page per school?

If so, where do I set the page breaks and how would I set this up please?  If you need any more information, please let me know.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list in order to group by school and set the page break property of the list to **End**.

As long as your table and graph data fit to one page, you can position report components as your sample layout

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  A list is just what I need.  I found a training video on lists here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bs2iHpVTuSw